# Bizarre issue with pandas' .groupby function, when function applied to rows

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy

I have a set of CSV data that is `4203x37` which I reshape to `50436x4` in order to find the Euclidean distance between 12 sets of 3D points, recorded at each time-step. This does not work for my actual data, but bizarrely enough when I recreated the data with random numbers it works, code follows...

Here is the code for my actual data, the one which does not work.

```
df_f_2_norm = df_f.loc[:,'Time':'label37'] # Select columns
N = 12 # Nr of points

# Drop label1 column for later use
df_f_2_norm_time = df_f_2_norm['Time']
df_f_2_norm = df_f_2_norm.drop('Time',1)

# Get shape of data frame
shp = df_f_2_norm.shape

# Use numpy.reshape to reshape the underlying data in the DataFrame
df_f_2_norm = pd.DataFrame(df_f_2_norm.values.reshape(-1,3),columns=list('XYZ'))
df_f_2_norm["Time"] = np.repeat(np.array(df_f_2_norm_time), N) # Number of points per time-label: 12

# Find the Euclidean distance (2-norm)
N_lim = int(0.5*N*(N-1)) 
result_index = ['D{}'.format(tag) for tag in range(1,N_lim+1)] # Column labels
two_norm = df_f_2_norm.groupby('Time')[["X", "Y", "Z"]].apply(lambda g: pd.Series(pdist(g), index=result_index))
```

Now if we look at the shape of the `two_norm` it should have the shape of `4203x66` i.e. 66 euclidean distances for 12 points, per time-stamp of which there are 4203, one per row.

What the actual answer comes out as is in fact: `AssertionError: Index length did not match values` - so it doesn't like the column labels that I have given it. Fine, if we remove the labels and just do instead

```
two_norm = df_f_2_norm.groupby('Time')[["X", "Y", "Z"]].apply(lambda g: pd.Series(pdist(g))
```

Then we get a shape (`print two_norm.shape`) of `(8307846,)` - I do not quite understand what has happened here, but it appears that it is not even stacking all the results on top of each other.

It gets better though, because the following code does work up until row 1140, so if we let

```
df_f_2_norm = df_f_2_norm[:1140]
```

Then we get the following shape: `(95,66)`

Which is correct up until that point, but if we do

```
df_f_2_norm = df_f_2_norm[:1152]
```

It instead gives: `(6480,)`

So something has obviously gone pear-shaped there, but if we actually look at the data around that point, nothing appears to strange.

```
             X         Y        Z   Time
1127  -614.770   207.624  120.859  2.533
1128   791.318   291.591   64.160  2.550
1129   728.892   283.473 -207.306  2.550
1130   939.871   251.387 -145.103  2.550
1131   702.987   287.165  398.151  2.550
1132   480.309   285.745  590.925  2.550
1133   723.493   248.699  607.543  2.550
1134   255.664   183.618 -108.176  2.550
1135   -90.333   196.879 -261.102  2.550
1136  -442.132   236.314 -419.216  2.550
1137   133.428   216.805  242.896  2.550
1138  -242.201   192.100  191.588  2.550
1139  -616.844   210.060  123.202  2.550
1140  -655.054  1390.084 -359.369  1.100
1141  -726.517  1222.015 -590.799  1.100
1142  -671.655  1146.959 -797.080  1.100
1143  -762.048  1379.722    8.505  1.100
1144  -981.748  1169.959   72.773  1.100
1145 -1011.853   968.364  229.070  1.100
1146  -778.290   827.571 -370.463  1.100
1147  -761.608   460.835 -329.487  1.100
1148  -815.330    77.501 -314.721  1.100
1149  -925.764   831.944  -34.206  1.100
1150 -1009.297   475.362  -73.077  1.100
1151 -1193.310   139.839 -142.666  1.100
1152  -631.630  1388.573 -353.642  1.117
1153  -697.771  1234.274 -593.501  1.117
```

So that is just odd. So I tried to replicate the problem with random numbers but it all works perfectly, even the labels, which just makes no sense...

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import string
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform
# Computes the distance between m points using Euclidean distance (2-norm)
# as the distance metric between the points. The points are arranged as m 
# n-dimensional row vectors in the matrix X.

# Test data frame
N = 12 # Nr of points
col_ids = string.letters[:N]
df = pd.DataFrame(
      np.random.randn(4203, 3*N+1), 
      columns=['Time']+['{}_{}'.format(letter, coord) for letter in col_ids for coord in list('xyz')])

# Drop time column for later use
df_time = df['Time']
df = df.drop('Time',1)

print df.shape

# Use numpy.reshape to reshape the underlying data in the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(-1,3), columns=list('XYZ'))
df["Time"] = np.repeat(np.array(df_time), N)

print df.shape

# Find the Euclidean distance (2-norm)
N_lim = int(0.5*N*(N-1))
result_index = ['D{}'.format(coord) for coord in range(1,N_lim+1)]
two_norm = df.groupby('Time')[["X", "Y", "Z"]].apply(lambda g: pd.Series(pdist(g), index=result_index))

print two_norm.shape
```

Which has the output (from the three print statements)

```
(4203, 36)
(50436, 4)
(4203, 66)
```

As you can see the shape of the final result is exactly as it should be. But there is truly nothing different (as far as I can tell) between these two sets of data, bar the numerical differences which should not have any impact on the actual shape of the resulting data frame.

What did I miss?

Thanks.

---

Original data can be found here (the one used in the first part of this post): https://www.dropbox.com/sh/80f8ue4ffa4067t/Pntl5-gUW4

It should be noted that the .csv file found in the dropbox is the data frame `df_f_2_norm` - hence it is not the raw data, but the re-shaped version (so the first line of code in above, does not need to be executed to get to this state, as it has already been performed).

Comment: can u share your data via Dropbox in a csv/hdf (the input data). what version of pandas/numpy

Comment: The original data can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/80f8ue4ffa4067t/Pntl5-gUW4 - my version of pandas is 0.12.0 and numpy is 1.7.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run the following code

```
df_f_2_norm.Time.value_counts()
```

Then you can find that not all time value has 12 rows.

Here is the output:

```
1.333    492
1.383    492
1.317    492
1.400    492
1.467    492
1.450    492
1.483    492
1.417    492
1.500    492
1.367    492
1.350    492
1.433    492
1.533    480
1.517    480
1.550    468
...
4.800    12
4.600    12
4.750    12
4.833    12
4.667    12
4.700    12
4.650    12
4.683    12
4.633    12
4.617    12
4.817    12
4.583    12
4.733    12
4.767    12
4.783    12
Length: 272, dtype: int64
```

If you want to group the dataframe every 12 rows, you can:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform

df_f_2_norm = pd.read_csv("astrid_data.csv")
g = np.repeat(np.arange(df_f_2_norm.shape[0]//12), 12)

N = 12

N_lim = int(0.5*N*(N-1)) 
result_index = ['D{}'.format(tag) for tag in range(1,N_lim+1)] # Column labels
two_norm = df_f_2_norm.groupby(g)[["X", "Y", "Z"]].apply(lambda g: pd.Series(pdist(g), index=result_index))
```

Comment: Cheers for your reply HYRY. What I do not understand then is why is this line not working `df_f_2_norm["Time"] = np.repeat(np.array(df_f_2_norm_time), N) # Number of points per time-label: 12` - the entire point of that line is to create 12 copies of each time-stamp. But that is not working then for some reason?