# Applying function, via df.groupby(), to pandas DataFrame - causing difficulties

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have run into, what I think, is a fairly simple problem yet again. I would like to apply the following function to a pandas data frame.

```
def cartesian_distance(A): # Cartesian distance function
    return [y - x for x, y in it.combinations(A, 2)]
```

As can be seen, this is a terribly easy function that is meant to take the difference between all pairs of values from the passed pandas row. If it is passed a row of length 6 then it will return 6*(6-1)*0.5 = 15 values, and so on. In my case my rows of data are 12 long and will thus return 66 resultant values (distances).

This is what I do:

```
import pandas as pd 
import itertools as it
import numpy as np

N = 12

def cartesian_distance(A):
    return [y - x for x, y in it.combinations(A, 2)]

# Use numpy.reshape to reshape the underlying data in the DataFrame
df_f_z = pd.DataFrame(df_f_z.values.reshape(-1,1),columns=list('Z'),index = arange(df_f_z.shape[0]*df_f_z.shape[1]))
```

What happens in the above line is that the data frame `df_f_z` is reshaped from (4203,12) to (50436,1)

```
time_id = np.repeat(np.arange(df_f_z.shape[0]//N), N) # temporary time-label group identifers
```

The above is used to create time-label groups such that the function applies to one group at a time.

```
N_lim = int(0.5*N*(N-1))
result_index = ['Dz_{}'.format(tag) for tag in range(1,N_lim+1)]
cart_dist = df_f_z.groupby(time_id)[["Z"]].apply(lambda g: pd.Series(cartesian_distance(g), index=result_index))
```

Predictably this does not work. I get the following error:

```
AssertionError: Index length did not match values
```

In essence I was trying to employ the same method as demonstrated in this question: [Bizarre issue with pandas' .groupby function, when function applied to rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20983419/bizarre-issue-with-pandas-groupby-function-when-function-applied-to-rows) but simply just using a different function, applied to vaguely the same data. As it turns out it was not as simple as that.

If anyone could provide some pointers, that would be most kind. Furthermore the reshaped pandas array `df_f_z` can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/80f8ue4ffa4067t/Pntl5-gUW4 (if anyone is interested).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to make it work for my application.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import itertools as it
import string

# Test data frame
N = 6
col_ids = string.letters[:N]
df = pd.DataFrame(
     np.random.randint(20, size=(5,N)),
     columns=['{}_z'.format(letter) for letter in col_ids])

N_lim = int(0.5*N*(N-1))
result_index = ['Dz_{}'.format(tag) for tag in range(1,N_lim+1)]

def cart_dist_2(A): # Cartesian distance function
    return [y - x for x, y in it.combinations(A, 2)]

test_2 = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(cart_dist_2(x),index=result_index),axis=1)
```

Where the test data frame looks as such

```
  A_z  B_z  C_z  D_z  E_z  F_z
0   18   19    7    5   14    5
1   17    9    2   17    1    5
2   16   10   18   14   14    3
3    7    2   10    9    9   10
4   18    5   10   10    3   11
```

Again, we are looking for the difference between all possible combinations of entries per row. The resultant `test_2` data frame is given as:

```
print test_2.values

[[  1 -11 -13  -4 -13 -12 -14  -5 -14  -2   7  -2   9   0  -9]
 [ -8 -15   0 -16 -12  -7   8  -8  -4  15  -1   3 -16 -12   4]
 [ -6   2  -2  -2 -13   8   4   4  -7  -4  -4 -15   0 -11 -11]
 [ -5   3   2   2   3   8   7   7   8  -1  -1   0   0   1   1]
 [-13  -8  -8 -15  -7   5   5  -2   6   0  -7   1  -7   1   8]]
```

Hope this is useful for someone else.

To recap: I ignored grouping it and applied the function straight away to the rows of the data frame.